# fgetcsv not recognizing escape character correctly

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a file of CSV strings like the following:

```
"12345","445 Maple St.","Going to the "orange" store","610-123-4567"
```

I'm parsing each line using the following:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($file_matters, 500, ',', '"', '"')) !== FALSE)
```

Instead of getting an array like so:

```
array(4) (
  [0] => (string) 12345
  [1] => (string) 445 Maple St.
  [2] => (string) Going to the "orange" store
  [3] => (string) 610-123-4567
)
```

I'm getting:

```
array(4) (
  [0] => (string) 12345
  [1] => (string) 445 Maple St.
  [2] => (string) Going to the orange" store"
  [3] => (string) 610-123-4567
)
```

Notice the incorrect double quotes. They should be wrapped around orange like so `"orange"` but as you can see, they're not. I am utilizing the 5th parameter of `fgetcsv` which should automatically escape the double-quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the problem also occure if you remove the last parameter from your `fgetcsv` method?

Comment: @bpoiss yes, removing the last parameter `'"'` from the `fgetcsv` method gives me the exact same results...

Comment: Try `fgetcsv($file_matters, 500, ',', '', '\')`

Comment: use escape sting for orange\ "orange\"

Comment: @bpoiss still not working with that.. I get a PHP error `enclosure must be a character`

Comment: @VigneswaranS I have no control over the CSV file I receive. I was hoping the built-in mechanism for escaping quotes with PHP's `fgetcsv` would work... I'm a bit perplexed

Comment: I'm not sure that's valid CSV. You would need to escape the "orange" correctly, also, CSV does NOT require all columns to be enclosed within quotes.

Comment: It's an invalid CSV.... if the enclosure is used inside data, then it must be escaped..... and there's nothing escaping the `"` before or after `orange`.... for this to be valid with a `"` to escape `"` it should read `"12345","445 Maple St.","Going to the ""orange"" store","610-123-4567"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your CSV is actually valid syntax; for example this would be valid:

```
"12345","445 Maple St.",Going to the "orange" store,"610-123-4567"
```

Where as your excerpt is not valid because you have `"` inside of `"`.

A CSV does *NOT* require all fields to be enclosed in quotes, PHP can handle CSV rows with unquoted blocks too.

```
php > var_dump(
    >    str_getcsv('"12345","445 Maple St.",Going to the "orange" store,"610-123-4567"')
    > );
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "445 Maple St."
  [2]=>
  string(27) "Going to the "orange" store"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "610-123-4567"
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. This data comes from a client's export and has been importing fine into my system for months. This is the first time I've seen double quotes within a field. I'm going to tell them they need to properly escape their files so that they are valid CSV strings. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

you just get data from the csv file and by using (,). Then use trim () function to remove the double quote as given below. I hope ,I sloved your problem .

Book1.csv

```
"12345","445 Maple St.","Going to the "orange" store","610-123-4567"
```

and the code is

```
<?php
   $row = 1;
   $handle = fopen("Book1.csv", "r");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($file_matters,500, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $num = count($data);
      $row++;
      for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
      $hh=$data[$i];
          $a[]=trim($hh,'"') ;// remove "" and save in a array
     // $a=trim($hh,'"') ;
          //echo$a. "<br />\n";
      }
   }
   fclose($file_matters);
   print_r($a);
?>
```

result

```
Array ( [0] => 12345
        [1] => 445 Maple St.
        [2] => Going to the "orange" store
        [3] => 610-123-4567 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CSV, you need to escape the content.

```
$csvContent = str_replace(' "', ' \"', $csvContent);
$csvContent = str_replace('" ', '\" ', $csvContent);
```

Comment: I'm asking about the escape problem when using`fgetcsv`... not about how to escape the double quotes manually.