# Parse string containing inline HTML attribute declarations in potentially 4 different formats

Tags: php, csv, delimited

I need to parse strings like
`k1=v1, k2=v2, ... kn=vn` with primary delimiter (,) and key-value-delimiter (=) may vary.
The values may be quoted (" or ') and may contain the primary delimiter within the quotes.

As I saw no restrictions for this kind of usage in the PHP docs, I found `str_getcsv()` suitable.

But with a first test I found out, that the enclosure character was ignored:

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2023 11:41:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $S2 = 'name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick="getinfo($this, 99);"';
php > var_dump($S2);
string(60) "name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick="getinfo($this, 99);""
php > var_dump(str_getcsv($S2));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "name=ABCD"
  [1]=>
  string(11) " value=17.3"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " autoID"
  [3]=>
  string(23) " onclick="getinfo($this"
  [4]=>
  string(6) " 99);""
}
php > $S3 = 'name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick=|getinfo($this, 99);|';
php > var_dump($S3);
string(60) "name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick=|getinfo($this, 99);|"
php > var_dump(str_getcsv($S3, ',', '|'));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "name=ABCD"
  [1]=>
  string(11) " value=17.3"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " autoID"
  [3]=>
  string(23) " onclick=|getinfo($this"
  [4]=>
  string(6) " 99);|"
}
```

The quoted string "getinfo($this, 99);" include the primary delimiter (,) and is therefore split into two elements ignoring the quotes. Usage of other enclosure character  does not change anything.

So I'm wondering if this is a bug, a wrong usage or if my assumption, that str_getcsv is suitable for this operation, is wrong. Any help and comments appreciated.

Tested on different PHP environments with same result.

Comment: Somewhat related: [fgetcsv not recognizing escape character correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34881907/2943403)

Comment: When you change the enclosure character in `str_getcsv()` you also change in the CSV data, so the error remains. What is the real format?

Answer (score 1):

It's more a case of where the delimiters are.  The are meant to enclose the whole field and not just part of it.

So replace it with

```
$S3 = 'name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, |onclick=getinfo($this, 99);|';
```

will give you the result

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "name=ABCD"
  [1]=>
  string(11) " value=17.3"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " autoID"
  [3]=>
  string(27) "onclick=getinfo($this, 99);"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel, so this means str_getcsv is not suitable for the parsing required.

Comment: @RanneR So, you just consume the format, you don't also create it? If you really mean that you randomly get double quotes or pipe characters, neither make valid CSV, so it's no surprise that CSV parser won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and advice. As a conclusion `str_getcsv` is not an adequate solution to parse strings like the example. (although at a first glance it seemed to be).

**So I needed to write a small parser by my own:**

```php
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Convert string with attributes into array
    function string2attribute( string $attstring, array $options ): array {
        if ( empty( $attstring ) ) {return [];}
        $Q = [
            $options['quotes'][0] ?? '', 
            $options['quotes'][1] ?? ($options['quotes'][0] ?? '')
        ];
        $parts = []; $buf = ''; $inquote = 0; $inescape = False;
        foreach ( str_split( $attstring ) as $C ) {
            if ( $inescape ) {
                $buf .= $C; $inescape = False;
            }   else    {
                if ( $C == $options['escape'] ) {
                    $inescape = True;
                }   elseif  ( $C == $Q[1] && $inquote > 0 ) {
                    $buf .= $C; $inquote -= 1;
                }   elseif  ( $C == $Q[0] ) {
                    $buf .= $C; $inquote += 1;
                }   elseif  ( $C == $options['delim1'] && $inquote < 1 ) {
                        $parts[] = trim( $buf ); $buf = '';
                }   else    {
                    $buf .= $C;
                }
            }
        }
        if ( !empty( $buf ) ) {$parts[] = trim( $buf );}

        $out = [];
        foreach ( $parts as $part ) {
            $kv = explode($options['delim2'], $part, 2);
            $kv = array_map( 'trim', $kv );
            if ( count( $kv ) == 2 ) {
                $out[$kv[0]] = rtrim( ltrim( $kv[1], $Q[0] ), $Q[1] );
            }   else    {
                $out[$kv[0]] = True;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test program for this function:**

```php
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    header( "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" );

    $T = 'Test 1: like style definition';
    $S = 'display: block; width: 320px; font-size: 16px; color: #123456ab; border: 1px solid #333';
    $O = ['delim1'=>';', 'delim2'=>':', 'quotes'=>'', 'escape'=>'\\'];
    test_result( $T, $S, $O );


    $T = 'Test 2: like tag attributes';
    $S = 'name=ABCD value=17.3 autoID onclick="getinfo($this, 99);"';
    $O = ['delim1'=>' ', 'delim2'=>'=', 'quotes'=>'"', 'escape'=>''];
    test_result( $T, $S, $O );


    $T = 'Test 3: comma as primary delimiter';
    $S = 'name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick="getinfo($this, 99);"';
    $O = ['delim1'=>',', 'delim2'=>'=', 'quotes'=>'"', 'escape'=>'\\'];
    test_result( $T, $S, $O );


    $T = 'Test 4: with escape and different quotes';
    $S = 'name=ABCD, value=17\", autoID, onclick=<getinfo($this, 99);>';
    $O = ['delim1'=>',', 'delim2'=>'=', 'quotes'=>'<>', 'escape'=>'\\'];
    test_result( $T, $S, $O );

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function test_result( $title, $teststring, $options ) {
        $NL = "\r\n";
        echo $NL . $title . $NL . 'Teststring:' . $NL . $teststring;
        echo $NL . 'Options:' . $NL;
        print_r( $options );
        echo $NL . 'string2attribute( $Teststring, $Options ):' . $NL;
        print_r( string2attribute( $teststring, $options ) );
    }
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Results of the test:**

```
Test 1: like style definition
Teststring:
display: block; width: 320px; font-size: 16px; color: #123456ab; border: 1px solid #333
Options:
    [delim1] => ;
    [delim2] => :
    [quotes] => 
    [escape] => \

string2attribute( $Teststring, $Options ):
    [display] => block
    [width] => 320px
    [font-size] => 16px
    [color] => #123456ab
    [border] => 1px solid #333

Test 2: like tag attributes
Teststring:
name=ABCD value=17.3 autoID onclick="getinfo($this, 99);"
Options:
    [delim1] =>  
    [delim2] => =
    [quotes] => "
    [escape] => 

string2attribute( $Teststring, $Options ):
    [name] => ABCD
    [value] => 17.3
    [autoID] => 1
    [onclick] => getinfo($this, 99);

Test 3: comma as primary delimiter
Teststring:
name=ABCD, value=17.3, autoID, onclick="getinfo($this, 99);"
Options:
    [delim1] => ,
    [delim2] => =
    [quotes] => "
    [escape] => \

string2attribute( $Teststring, $Options ):
    [name] => ABCD
    [value] => 17.3
    [autoID] => 1
    [onclick] => getinfo($this, 99);

Test 4: with escape and different quotes
Teststring:
name=ABCD, value=17\", autoID, onclick=<getinfo($this, 99);>
Options:
    [delim1] => ,
    [delim2] => =
    [quotes] => <>
    [escape] => \

string2attribute( $Teststring, $Options ):
    [name] => ABCD
    [value] => 17"
    [autoID] => 1
    [onclick] => getinfo($this, 99);
```

Comment: I do not envy your task.  I was going to recommend a proper parser like https://3v4l.org/oX1kS but you are dealing without some gross input variability.